# Varying Length of Chapter Name and Page Number in a Header in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I have Chapter names with varying length and In the header I want the Chapter and the page number in the same line irrespective of the length of the Chapter name. I have tried the options,

Insert > Quick Parts > Field > StyleRef

But for Chapters with bigger length the page number gets cut. I want this to auto format irrespective of the length of the Chapter.

How do I prevent this from happening ?

Comment: It you always want all of the heading, you could put a table in the header with one row and two columns,  put the stylesheet field in one cell and the page number field in the other, then set the relevant table/row/cell properties so that the text wraps and the row will expand downwards to accommodate it.

Comment: No this is not the solution I'm looking for, its not within the guidelines. Can't we do it by creating separate section for each chapter ?

Comment: You can clarify your question to state the relevant guidelines that you have to work with. But why would creating a separates section for each chapter make any difference to the length of the heading?